# Perl try/catch block throws error in Error.pm

Tags: perl, exception

I have the following code in in a Perl script I'm writing:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DBI;
use Getopt::Long;
use Time::HiRes;
use Error qw(:try);

....

my $starttime = Time::HiRes::time;

try {
    my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Sybase:$server", $username, $password);
    $dbh->do("use $database");
    my $query="exec OfflineDatabaseReport";

    $row = $dbh->selectrow_hashref($query);

    $dbh->disconnect();
} catch Error with {
    print "boom";
    exit 1;
};
my $endtime = Time::HiRes::time;
my $timetaken = $endtime - $starttime;
```

The script worked fine until I wrapped the data access portion in the `try...catch` block. Now I get the following exception thrown:

> Can't use string ("1316135985.90893") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Error.pm line 217.

I did try setting:

```
no strict "refs";
```

But I still get the same error. Am I being naive in my usage of a `try/catch` block here?

Comment: From the description of that module on CPAN: *Using the "Error" module is no longer recommended due to the black-magical nature of its syntactic sugar, which often tends to break. Its maintainers have stopped actively writing code that uses it, and discourage people from doing so. See the "SEE ALSO" section below for better recommendations.* http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/Error-0.17016/lib/Error.pm

Comment: @brian - ah...that recommendation completely hit my blindspot. Feel free to facepalm.

Comment: I mean, I'm not saying that it's impossible that *someone* here might have some advice, but my interest in investigating the issue kinda stopped right there :-D

Comment: That's ok, that warning about black magic is good enough for me to lose interest in investigating it as well.

Comment: Also, don't forget to put a semicolon at the end of the `catch {...}` block -- that will come back to bite you in the you-know-where.

Comment: @Kev: If you're not doing anything fancy with `Error`, you could try replacing it with `Try::Tiny`. Almost a drop in replacement for simple `try { ... } catch { ... }` blocks.

Comment: The current URL to the CPAN module is http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/Error-0.17022/lib/Error.pm

Comment: For your information, since this question was posted, there is now a perfect implementation of try-catch in perl with [Nice::Try](https://metacpan.org/pod/Nice::Try)

Comment: @Jacques thanks for the info. I haven't touched Perl for a long time now, but will keep in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how the parser sees the code:

```
try({ ... }, catch(Error, with({ ... }, my $endtime = Time::HiRes::time)));
```

Meaning, it passes the result of setting `$endtime` to `Time::HiRes::time` as the 2nd argument of the `with BLOCK` sub. Looking at the source of `Error.pm`, I see:

```
sub with (&;$) {
    @_
}
```

Which means `with BLOCK,SCALAR` is a valid argument list. All it does is pass the arguments up to `catch`, which  interprets `my $endtime = Time::HiRes::time` as its `$clauses`. `catch` itself returns `$clauses`, which turns the whole statement into:

```
try({ ... }, my $endtime = Time::HiRes::time);
```

`try` assumes `$clauses` is a hashref, as you can see by the call to

```
$clauses->{'finally'}->()
    if(defined($clauses->{'finally'}));
```

So perl tries to use the value of `Time::HiRes::time` as a hashref, which it most certainly cannot, since it's actually a scalar with a value of "1316135985.90893".

So yeah, the semicolon at the end of the `catch` block.